# Wordpress Site Will Not Index In Google

Tags: wordpress

So, I've been banging my head against the wall on this for a while.

I have a WP site here: http://www.barre101.com. 
And my robots.txt is located here: http://www.barre101.com/robots.txt

For some crazy reasons, Google is not indexing any of my pages in the search results.

In Webmaster Tools, there have been no crawl errors, and it says that 19 pages were successfully crawled as early as yesterday.

I have successfully fetched my site in Webmaster Tools, and Googlebot successfully fetches the correct information on the page.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before? Any/all help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support request regarding a third-party software, here namely Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the source of your pages and i believe that your headers are not setted correctly to help in the process of indexing a site.

```
<meta name="description" content="full functionable, premium wordpress theme solution for your website.">
    <meta name="keywords" content=", proffesional wordpress theme, flexible wordpress theme, wordpress all in one theme, premium wordpress theme " />
```

Consider adding some relevant keywords and relevant description. Adding a sitemapindex.xml would also help a lot

also note that you headers contains these:

```
<meta name="robots" content="none" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="none" />
```

i think the following would work best in your case

```
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this information! I've made all the changes you mentioned. It looks likes the client was trying to use a plugin to generate all that information, but for some reason, it wasn't pulling in what was populated in the plugin options. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your sitemap is empty so you're giving him nothing to crawl ?

> http://www.barre101.com/sitemapindex.xml

Although if you have links from external sites, you will get indexed right away ... Do check your sitemap though, and correct that and then add it to sitemaps in webmaster tools.

Wordpress is really fast to index, really!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm going to jump in now and check out that error. I've never had an issue like this before, especially with WP! Like you said, they typically index themselves without much work at all.

Comment: Well normally they come with a robots.txt themselves (wordpress I mean), you appeared to be making some changes of your own ... make sure the sitemap is alright, then allow it a few days.

Comment: Agreed with legrandviking on the robots meta tag, I haven't looked there myself, you also need to correct that also!

Comment: Thanks everyone! I've made all the suggested changes, generated a new sitemap/sitemapindex, and added it to Webmaster Tools. Hopefully all of these suggestions do the trick!