# Custom Domain GoApp Site Not Indexing on Search Engines

Tags: google-app-engine, go, seo

I have been building several GoApp sites with GoLang backend and a lightweight html5/css3/javascript (usually AngularJS) front end. Most of these were for practice, but I have recently created my own personal site with this same pattern and decided that I wanted my own custom domain for it.

I followed the steps outlined here: [Google App Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) and everything seemed great. People were able to hit my site (with and without the www) and I was seeing traffic come through Google Analytics.

Now for the problem... as I was looking at various search engines and attempting to submit my site to the index, I am getting "Site Not Found" errors from the Search Engines. For Google and Bing I went into webmaster tools and everything looked fine on the diagnostics (Robots.txt and SiteMap.xml). However after a few days, I am still showing the site is not being indexed.

So the question is, does anyone know why I might be having issues? Nothing I have found seems to point to what the cause might be.

Some of the other SO pages I looked at first:

- [are .appspot google app engine sites restricted in crawl / search engine rankings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107756/are-appspot-google-app-engine-sites-restricted-in-crawl-search-engine-ranking)
- [Wordpress Site Will Not Index In Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864750/wordpress-site-will-not-index-in-google)
- [Google App Engine + Custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280542/google-app-engine-custom-domain)

Comment: I left my site off here because I am trying to make sure I am not considered to be advertising it. If it is needed I can provide that as well.

Comment: Google's algorithm works by finding your page through links on other websites. In the past, the only way I managed to get my site to be indexed by Google is to post a link to it from somewhere. Usually a forum or blog. This is where things like Stack Overflow's user profile or LinkedIn comes in useful for personal websites - list your url in your profile and soon Google will index it.

Comment: What does site:yoursite.com return in the google search box?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an [SEO question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281380/can-we-ask-seo-questions-on-stack-overflow).